# Bxslider Custom Pager Option

Tags: jquery, pager, bxslider

Check out my [bxslider](/questions/tagged/bxslider) [here](http://www.coppermstudio.com/indexNEW.html). I want to know what method I would use if I want to use the ribbons on the left to call specific slides to show. For example, if I click Photo-Fusion it would call the Photo-Fusion slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[untested] I think it's probably because it seems you haven't set a reference to the bxslider.  That's why you can't call the methods.

```
//hold a reference to the slider
var myBX;
$(document).ready(function(){
    myBX = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({...});
}
//later on...
$(#yourPhotoFusionButton").on("click",function(e){myBX.goToSlide(4);});
```

Look up the public methods here: http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: I haven't tried to call the method yet, just wondering what approach to take. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I think I'm making some progress. When you first open the page, the bxslider is set for auto. Once I click the particular slide I want it goes to that slide, but it still remains autopilot. How do I stop the slider once I call a certain slide.

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ritstyx/zpwHL/)

Comment: Try adding the stopAuto() method to the anonymous function bound to the "click" event.

    $(#yourPhotoFusionButton").on("click",function(e){myBX.goToSlide(4);myBX.stopAuto();});

Comment: I got it to work! But using two click events. Maybe we aren't putting the stopAuto() in the proper place when combining them.
$("#box").on("click",function(e){myBX.goToSlide(1);});
$("#box").on("click",function(e){myBX.stopAuto();});

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I'm not sure why it didn't work all within 1 function.  Having 2 seperate callbacks for the same click event isn't efficient.  Maybe try function(e){$(myBX).goToSlide(1);$(myBX).stopAuto();}

Comment: Nope. Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ritstyx/zpwHL/). Still not sure how to combine them into one function.

Comment: Hmm...I'll have some time to look hopefully by tomorrow late.

Comment: For some reason, I can't log into JSFiddle.  anyway, here's what I would have written there:

var myBX;
$(document).ready(function(){
  myBX = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
 pager: true,
 mode: 'fade',
 auto: true,
 randomStart: true,
 preloadImages: 'visible',
 adaptiveHeight: true,
 responsive: true,
 controls: false,
 autoControls: false,
 });
});

$("#box").on("click",boxClickHandler);

function boxClickHandler(e){
    myBX.goToSlide(1);
    myBX.stopAuto();
}

Also, a gotcha: in your fiddle, you didn't designate jquery on the left side.  Don't worry, it's gotten me too.  Let me know!

Comment: Voilà! I appreciate all your help, kind sir.